# Show images added at run time user in Angular

Tags: html, angular

I'm working with Angular 5 and I'm trying to show images that the user has uploaded from their side.

When user upload an image, I put this image inside the assets folder then I will save the image path and name in database (**assets/images/userupload/example.jpg**).

then I will set this path as an image srouce `<img src="assets/images/userupload/example.jpg" />`

but it shows ***404 (not found)*** error. Getting the url from the page source and trying to open it in new tab, I get this error ***ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'assets/images/userupload/example.jpg'***

after angular gets compiled, every thing works perfectly, and non of the errors above appears any more.

could someone point, what I'm doing wrong and should I place it in the assets folder in the first place?

EDIT:
html code

```
<img *ngIf="carModel.imageUrl && carModel.imageId" [src]="carModel.imageUrl" height=250 width=400 alt="car model">
```

Comment: Could you show your actual angular template code instead of a generic HTML code?

Comment: what backend server do you use?

Comment: @jaboja I have updated the question

Comment: is the image getting uploaded succesfully? is it available in the assets folder after you upload?

Comment: @IBRA, you need to provide full server url path, instead of relative path

Comment: @MohdTabishBaig yes, the path and the name appears correctly inside the assets folder

Comment: @JayakrishnanGounder I have. same issue. and when getting the full path and place it into the browser directly i get Cannot match any routes error as descried in the question

Comment: what backend server do you use (to upload image)?

Comment: @IBRA why are two slash after the images? Segment: 'assets/images//userupload/example.jpg'

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski I'm using asp.net core web api. and using swagger to generate the services

Comment: @Chris sorry this was a typo, i have updated the question

Comment: try this: `<img src="/assets/images/userupload/example.jpg" />`

Comment: @IBRA - so your asp server after user upload image, put it to `dist/assets` (dist - folder where angular app was build)  ? Are you sure and check that `https://your.domain/assets/images/userupload/example.jpg` is really there?

Comment: Reason why it's not working is because assets folder get copied over during first compile, so when you add new files it's not in webpack dev server.

Comment: @penleychan this sound right, but how to fix this? i'm new to angular, but if i'm not wrong i need to set the output and input in assets right?

Comment: @IBRA, AFAIK you can't, assets folder is only for static assets that are not expected to change unless you redeploy. You should host those image files somewhere else.

Comment: @penleychan thanks, this was not clear for me, would you please put this comment in an answer to mark it. and if you could suggest a link for a solution to the scenario described in my question. it would be great. thanks

Comment: @IBRA, I wouldn't consider my comment as an answer. I would suggest you try it without `ng serve` and host it on a local server or something to test it out via `ng build`. Pretty sure that it will work when you upload an image since it is not using webpack dev server.

Comment: @penleychan thanks for your explanation. and you did answer my question and pointed out what I was doing wrong. I will try your suggestion, hopefully it will fix the issue. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Have you test stop ng serve and restart ng serve ?
With firefox have you test your picture in the absolute path ?

exemple:
http://mycomputer/assets/images/userupload/example.jpg

Comment: yes, as I mentioned in the question, If I re build the angular application. everything works fine.

Comment: And the picture path in absolute is ok ?, if you try in lunch server, try read access.log or error log in apache ou nginx ? have you try empty cache ?

Answer (score 0):

Check two things:

1. You are using a relative path. What is it really pointing at this way and is it exactly the path you wanted it to point at?
2. Your error indicates that your server does not recognize the path as an assets path.

   - **If you are running a developer server with `ng serve`:**
     Check in your `.angular-cli.json` file if the path you are trying to load the assets from is listed as an asset path, i.e.:

     ```
     {
       …
       "apps": [
         {
           …
           "assets": [
             "assets",
             …
           ],
           …
         }
       ],
       …
     }
     ```
   - **If you are serving with a webserver,** check if the assets path is configured to be served from filesystem and not via Angular.